# Compare rows and calculate column of same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

If you see 2 Abc's then calculate with total like 9*2 = 18
and second row as 15*2 = 30 like that

```
add Fun1    Fun2    Fun3
9   Abc     Wxy     Abc
15  def     Abc     Abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A series of `case` expressions should do the trick:

```
SELECT add * ((CASE Fun1 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
              (CASE Fun2 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
              (CASE Fun3 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS total
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Ahh beat me too it while I was making a SQL Fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Used `addn` instead of `add` as `add` is a reserved word in SQL

```
SELECT addn, Fun1, Fun2, Fun3, ((CASE Fun1 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                                (CASE Fun2 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                                (CASE Fun3 WHEN 'Abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * addn AS result
FROM yourtable
```

Output:

```
addn    Fun1    Fun2    Fun3    result
9       Abc     Wxy     Abc     18
15      def     Abc     Abc     30
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec218/3/0